# Chart.js - not responsive when change container height

Tags: charts, chart.js

I add doughnut chart to dashboard box. Dashboard box can change width&height. When I change width - chart change size, but when increase/reduce height chart did't chage own size.[image]

My chart.js options:

```js
options: {
  segmentShowStroke: false,
  percentageInnerCutout : 64,
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scaleShowLabels: false,
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
}
```